# div innerHtml string after null character ignored in WebBrowser control but not in IE8

Tags: c#, html, winforms, vbscript, webbrowser-control

**Background:** Our application before runs in Windows 7 and uses IE 8 as the browser to display HTML. But when we upgraded to Windows 10, we cannot use IE 8 anymore, so we created a WinForms application hosting a WebBrowser control to display the HTML.

**Problem**: We noticed that some string information is not displayed anymore when using the WebBrowser control and found out that the string which has a null character in the middle will discard the succeeding characters. In IE 8, the null was just ignored and it was able to display the whole string. I created a simple HTML to replicate the issue:

```
<HTML>
<TITLE>TEST</TITLE>
<HEAD>
<script language="VBScript">
Dim str
Sub Window_OnLoad()

str= "<TABLE >" & _
"<TR ><TD >0</TD></TR>" & _
"<TR ><TD >1" & chr(&H0) & "</TD></TR>" &_
"<TR ><TD >2</TD></TR><TR ><TD >3</TD></TR></TABLE>"

MsgBox str

document.all.mydiv.innerHtml = str
End Sub
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY >
<div id="mydiv">

</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Output (IE 8):

```
0
1
2
3
```

Output (WebBrowser control):

```
0
1
```

In our application, the 2nd data retrieved (in the example above "1") that is set to the table element contains null after it, and what happens in the WebBrowser control is that the data after the null are discarded, thus not being able to print the whole data on the table. However, in IE8, it just seems to ignore the null and display the whole data on the table. Is there some way to make the WebBrowser control behave like in IE 8?

**Solutions tried\Investigation results**:

1. We already set the [Browser Emulation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN%5D) correctly so that the web browser will behave like IE 8 but it still not working. (tried both 8000 and 8888)
2. We tried to use meta [X-UA-Compatible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/ie_standards/ms-iedoco/380e2488-f5eb-4457-a07a-0cb1b6e4b4b5) instead of the Browser Emulation, but still not working. (tried both "IE=8" and "IE=EmulateIE8")
3. We tried setting all kinds of DOCTYPE but it also doesn't work.
4. In the sample code above I put a MsgBox to see the data to be set in the inner HTML and IE8 did not alert the data after the null. It was only able to ignore the null when setting it to the inner HTML. Could this be a special behavior of the inner HTML in IE?
5. I don't know if necessary but I tried to translate the code in javascript and still got the same results for both IE8 and WebBrowser control.

Comment: When making a request the UserAgent is sent to specify the browser that is going to be used to display the results.  You may need to add the UserAgent http header to your request.  See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent

Comment: @jdweng I checked the User-Agent when using IE8 and modified the web browser to use that User-Agent when Navigating but it doesn't work. The data after null is still not displayed like in IE8. This was the User-Agent alerted now by both IE8 and our custom browser: `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)`

Comment: Do you  think it is a font issue?  You may not have the same fonts installed in Windows 10 that you had previously.

Comment: Can you replace the null with something else?

Comment: Why don't you just dump VBScript? That's ancient (and deprecated) history.

Comment: @Jimi It might be ancient but it’s sure not deprecated (The Windows Scripting Host still ships with the latest Windows OS).

Comment: It's *deprecated* (dismissed, abandoned, not supported) in Internet Explorer, since version 9. It's only available in EMIE8 (Enterprise Mode IE v.8). You cannot use it in IE11 in Edge Mode. -- There's no possible reason you want to use this thing. Do the same in JavaScript, almost identical code.

Comment: @jdweng - It's not a font issue. I tried my custom browser in the same Windows 7 environment and unfortunately still have the same results. 
(edit: separated comments for clarity)

Comment: @Jimi - I tried with javascript as stated in my 5th investigation result and the resuls are the same. Also, we are working with very old code that's why it's in VBScript and we sadly cannot change that.

Comment: @wazz - if we replace null then yes it would display the rest of the string, because I think null is treated as end of the string, which is the problem of this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

While it was clear from the question that document mode was considered, what was overlooked is that CASE matters when moving to a newer document mode. Also, it was stated that the output was complete (0,1,2,3) with IE 8, but was incomplete (0,1) using the WebBrowser control.

We can simplify testing by running the page as an HTA. When doing that, we can see that in IE=8 mode (and lower) the output is (0,1) and in IE=9 (or IE=10) mode the output is (0,1,2,3).

The case problem in the original code is this line:

```
Sub Window_OnLoad()
```

It should be:

```
Sub window_onload
```

Specifically, `Window` must be `window` (all lowercase) in IE=9 or higher modes. The case of "onload" and the unnecessary parenthesis make no functional difference, but have been changed to their standard formats. Please note that *calling* a sub from an element in IE=9 or higher mode requires parenthesis but the Sub itself does not need them when there are no parameters to be passed.

Here's a minimal version of the code that outputs (0,1,2,3) and ignores the null character:

**Test.hta**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
<script language="VBScript">
Sub window_onload
  d1.innerHTML = "<table><tr><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>1" & chr(&H0) & "</td></tr><tr><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td></tr></table>"
End Sub
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id=d1></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the code above, if `IE=9` is changed to `IE=8` the output will be (0,1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes it works for IE=9 but our application needs to simulate IE8.

Comment: This was almost 2 years ago, so what did you end up doing for a workaround?

Comment: We just accepted this as normal behavior when using WebBrowser control. For the fix of the actual root cause of the bug (the NULL), we decided to modify the code to strip off the unnecessary NULL characters from the source data.